# Unable to extract single value from Json object only getting [Object promise] from API

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, promise

First of I'm really new to Javascript and programming in general and

This is a small part of code that is suppose to take the Json object filter it to the single string "poster_path" in the array and then send out an alert and console log it.

Now on the console log I get the desired string but the alert gives an "[Object promise]" instead of the string

```
async function getposter() 
{

   let response = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XXXXX&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1');

   let poster = await response.json()

   .then(poster => console.log(poster.results[0].poster_path));

   return poster
}



alert(getposter())
```

Comment: you have to await `getposter()` since its a promise. Or `getposter().then(p => alert(p))`

Answer (score 0):

getposter() is a promise, you need to await them to resolver before use.

An better example of how you can use or handle with your request is the code below:

```
async function getposter() {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XXXXX&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1'
  );

  const poster = await response.json()
  const { poster_path } = poster.results[0];

  return poster_path
}

(async () => {
  try {
    alert(await getposter());
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
})();
```

Comment: That's great that its working now but its still treating poster_path as an Object that's causing issues when I'm trying to create a link.